# WordPress links all redirect to double URL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess

A fellow developer built a WordPress website on his local machine. He then migrated the whole installation onto a server. Naturally, all the links in sql were set to `localhost:8888`. I then ran a SQL update to fix the links so they pointed to the correct domain (which right now is an `ipaddress/~username` link). I've double checked my work, and it all looks correct.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'feed://www.olddomain.com', 'feed://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

I used that coding, but with the appropriate domain information in there.

So now here’s what’s happening.

Whenever I go to the homepage, it works, but the images don't show up. then i click on a link, or travel to teh wp-admin, and it shows the url twice in the urlbar. so it goes to something like:

```
http://newdomain.com/~user/http://newdomain.com/~user/post-name-blah-blah-blah
```

the `.htaccess` file is all default, (if WordPress is in a subdirectory should it have a rewrite rule for that instead of just /?)

What could cause every link on the site to go to the same url twice, if none of them are listed like that in SQL?

UPDATE:

Alright, so I erased the whole database and reset that up, and then the site works fine. of course that means I lose all my content. I'm guessing i screwed up the sql query's somewhere down the line. But I can't find anywhere that has two urls, or would even cause this. More updates coming as I figure out my issue.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I Solved it! Hopefully if anyone else comes here and has the same mistake, this will help. In the `wp_options` table the rows for `site_url` and `home` need to have `http://` in front of them. Somehow on my, my sql query busted that portion. Of course I didn't notice because the address looked correct, because that normally works. but in this case it caused a never-ending loop with some links, and in others just doubled the address.

Comment: You saved my day

Comment: have exact same problem. example.com/wp-admin redirected to example.com/wp-admin/example.com/wp-login.php and failed obviously but example.com/wp-login.php was working but later resources seems to be f up ;) . Fixing site url to the one with http did the job.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the solution! Saved me from a big headache.

Comment: After 6 years, again THANKS! I was adding just the IP address (forgetting HTTP://)  and it was driving me insane.

Answer (score 6):

While doing the database adjustments you did might work, I find them to be problematic. Instead whenever one moves a WordPress site, you need to properly adjust configurations in your WordPress install in the `wp-config.php` file on the following variables:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://newdomain.com/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://newdomain.com/');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/your/wordpress/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://newdomain.com/wp-content');
```

This will force your install to use the `newdomain.com` URLs.  Also, when you do this the first time set the `RELOCATE` setting to `true` like this:

```
define('RELOCATE', true);
```

That basically tells WordPress to rejigger (that’s my technical term for it) it’s stored settings for the new settings. And after you have reloaded your site & it works as expected, set `RELOCATE` setting back to `false` like this:

```
define('RELOCATE', false);
```

But you also say this:

> (if WordPress is in a subdirectory should it have a rewrite rule for
>   that instead of just /?)

That has to change if you are placing WordPress in a subdirectory. So let’s assume that WordPress is in a subdirectory called `coolsite/`. Then change the default WordPress `.htaccess` from this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

To this; note the way I changed the `RewriteBase` & the last `RewriteRule`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /coolsite/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /coolsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Well thank you for letting me know about this better way of doing it. Unfortunately none of these things changed anything for me. I'm still getting these errors just the same as before.

Answer (score -1):

Put `http://` in front of `site_url` and `Home_url` in the `wp_option` table of your database.