# Domain added onto resource paths in wp-admin after converting to multi site

Tags: php, wordpress

I've configured a wordpress multisite. The domain is `website1`.

Additional sites are setup as `website1/foo` and `website1/bar`

Visitng `website1/foo/wp-admin/` & `website1/bar/wp-admin/` function as expected.

Visiting `website1/wp-admin/` results in wordpress serving resources as `website1/wp-admin/website1`

Can anyone point me in the direction to resolve this?

My wp-config contains:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'website1');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

.htaccess contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a result of the `wp_options` table containing the domain without `http:// | https://`

I updated the `siteurl` and `home` by prepending `//` to the option_value column.

So `website1` became `//website1`

Thanks to this post for putting me on the right path. [WordPress links all redirect to double URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297263/wordpress-links-all-redirect-to-double-url)